# Can I draft an Outlook email .msg file in R (preferably with attachments)?

Tags: r, outlook, r-markdown

I am not able to benefit from some of R's nice packages for managing Outlook and auto sending email (due to IT restrictions) but I would still like to save myself some time by setting up the .msg files (with attachments) so that I can manually send.

Is this possible?

I have tried to benefit from the various packages to do this but get errors. I believe this is due to IT restrictions.

I have done parameterized report generation with Rmarkdown so I'm wondering if something similar is possible for .msg files (or a somewhat simple workaround to save time). Each email would have 3 attachments and some custom text based on parameters.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, can you please mention your research specifically by mentioning the exact packages?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this package myself but it says it can save files as .msg and may answer your question. Looks like it is not currently in active development but the author seems to be active on github still.

https://github.com/lgaborini/outlookMailer